# is Postgres Float equivalent to sql server float

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I am converting an sqlserver DB to PostgreSQL and I saw some column declared as Float in SQL Server. I am about to just declare that column float in PostgreSQL but I wonder if this conversion will be good enough. Should it be better to declare FLOAT(20) in PostgreSQL? or just FLOAT will be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both DBMS interpret FLOAT with no precision parameter as `FLOAT(53)` (a full-precision double precision float). Precision values of 24 or less may change the internal representation into a single-precision float, which seems to be your case given you have a `FLOAT(20)`.

In both Postgres and MS SQL, the database will just use a column of type `REAL` (32 bits) or `DOUBLE PRECISION` (64 bits) internally. The precision parameter merely ensures that the mantissa of your float has a specific maximum precision (a longer mantissa gets truncated).

`FLOAT(20)` would be equivalent on both DBMS, and `FLOAT` would give you an extra 33 bits of precision, which you may or may not need/want. `FLOAT`/`REAL`/`DOUBLE PRECISION` columns are pretty uncommon in SQL, tough, most people will use a NUMERIC instead, and the Postgres documentation actually points this out. Given this is a migration, though, you might want to be conservative about this.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15